# How to run shell script via kubectl without interactive shell

Tags: shell, ssh, scripting, devops, kubectl

I am trying to export a configuration from a service called keycloak by using shell script. To do that, `export.sh` will be run from the pipeline.

the script connects to k8s cluster and run the command in there.

So far, everything goes okay the export work perfectly.

But when I try to exit from the k8s cluster with exit and directly end the shell script. therefore it will move back to the pipeline host without staying in the remote machine.

**Running the command from the pipeline**

`ssh -t ubuntu@example1.com 'bash' < export.sh`

**export.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
set -e

rm -rf /tmp/realm-export

if [ $(ps -ef | grep "keycloak.migration.action=export" | grep -v grep | wc -l) != 0 ]; then
    echo "Another export is currently running"
    exit 1
fi

kubectl -n keycloak exec -it keycloak-0 bash

mkdir /tmp/export
/opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/standalone.sh -Dkeycloak.migration.action=export -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir -Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/tmp/export -Dkeycloak.migration.usersExportStrategy=DIFFERENT_FILES -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100
rm /tmp/export/master-*
exit
kubectl -n keycloak cp keycloak-0:/tmp/export /tmp/realm-export
exit
exit

scp ubuntu@example1.com:/tmp/realm-export/* ./configuration2/realms/
```

After the first exit the whole shell script stopped, the left commands doesn't work. it won't stay on ubuntu@example1.com.
Is there any solutions?

Comment: Is there a reason for multiple `exit`?

Comment: @ConstantinHong The first `exit` is to exit from the k8s cluster the second one is to exit from ubuntu@example1.com the third one is wrong there

Comment: Basically, `exit` terminates your script. Which line shows the k8s cluster script? In my opinion, the first `exit` terminates your `export.sh` script. Also if you need to run all commands, you should not put `exit` in the middle of the script. (except the `exit 1`.)

Comment: After `kubectl -n keycloak exec -it keycloak-0 bash` go inside the cluster after the command has been done i want to exit from that and run command inside the `ubuntu@example1.com` how can i do that?

Comment: I believe `kubectl -n keycloak exec -it keycloak-0 -- <your command>`. Try `kubectl -n keycloak exec -it keycloak-0 -- touch test_file`. Does this make test_file? This command will make the file and exit. also it won't require interactive commands.  [kubernetes manual](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands)

Comment: Okay then how can i exit from ubuntu@example1.com to do the `scp ubuntu@example1.com:/tmp/realm-export/* ./configuration2/realms/`

Comment: What you said it's not helpful. I suggested code as an answer below. Let's discuss it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Run the commands inside without interactive shell using HEREDOC(EOF).

It's not `EOF`. It's `'EOF'`. this prevents a variable expansion in the current shell.

But in the other script's `/tmp/export/master-*` will expand as you expect.

```
kubectl -n keycloak exec -it keycloak-0 bash <<'EOF'
<put your codes here, which you type interactively>
EOF
```

## export.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
set -e

rm -rf /tmp/realm-export

if [ $(ps -ef | grep "keycloak.migration.action=export" | grep -v grep | wc -l) != 0 ]; then
    echo "Another export is currently running"
    exit 1
fi

# the suggested code.
kubectl -n keycloak exec -it keycloak-0 bash <<'EOF'
<put your codes here, which you type interactively>
EOF

mkdir /tmp/export
/opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/standalone.sh -Dkeycloak.migration.action=export -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir -Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/tmp/export -Dkeycloak.migration.usersExportStrategy=DIFFERENT_FILES -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100
rm /tmp/export/master-*

kubectl -n keycloak cp keycloak-0:/tmp/export /tmp/realm-export

scp ubuntu@example1.com:/tmp/realm-export/* ./configuration2/realms/
```

Even if `scp` runs successfully or not, this code will exit.

Comment: Thanks a lot this fixed what i was trying to do appreciated.